# listening to invitations in google play services

Tags: google-play-games

I have a few problems listening to incoming invitetions,

1) onInvitationReceived is not called when an invite is received when app on (i registerInvitationListener to my gamesClient in onSignInSucceeded)

2) no notification will pop up when the app isnt open aswell.

i was trying to add plusClient in the BaseGameActivity but still no change, is something need to be done to make the app listen to invites that im missing?
do i need to publish it to see invite notifications?
sending invites to someone that doesnt have the app should send him to google play?

Comment: Are you registered in signInSucceded?                                 @Override
protected void onSignInSucceeded() { // or onConnected(), if not using BaseGameActivity
    // ...
    getGamesClient().registerInvitationListener(this); 
    // ...
}

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Invitations are delivered via push notification (like GCM), so several factors may influence in the system's ability to deliver them. If you don't get invites through the notification bar, there is something wrong with the network or with the device. Push messages are somehow not getting through to it. Can you send a gtalk ping to the device, and does it appear on the notification bar?

Once you do get to a state where notifications via notification bar are showing, but are not able to receive them in your app, I'd check:

(1) Are you registering an anonymous listener as an invitation listener? That's problematic. Take a look at [this tip](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#anonymous_listeners).

(2) Are you waiting a sufficient amount of time? Sometimes it may take > 30sec before a notification arrives, depending on network connectivity. With good network it should be faster, though.